# Use Python To Find Optimal Match Ups Between Two Teams

Tags: python

I am working on a Python program that uses Beautiful Soup to gather statistics from a website and process it to find the optimal match up between two 5 player teams. So far I have been able to gather the historical data and calculate the head to head statistics between each of the players. It then stores this data in a list.

Data format for the head to head statistics (column headers):

```
[['MyTeamPlayerName', TotalPoints, PointsWon, WinPct, ProjectedPoints], (vs.) ['OpposingTeamPlayerName', TotalPoints, PointsWon, WinPct, ProjectedPoints]]
```

Here are the head to head stats for each player on Team1 vs each player on Team2 when I print each row:

```
[[['Team1_Player1', 572, 394.0, 0.689, 2.76], ['Team2_Player1', 572, 178.0, 0.311, 1.24]]]
[[['Team1_Player1', 156, 90.5, 0.58, 2.32], ['Team2_Player2', 156, 65.5, 0.42, 1.68]]]
[[['Team1_Player1', 832, 449.5, 0.54, 2.16], ['Team2_Player3', 832, 382.5, 0.46, 1.84]]]
[[['Team1_Player1', 728, 372.0, 0.511, 2.04], ['Team2_Player4', 728, 356.0, 0.489, 1.96]]]
[[['Team1_Player1', 676, 342.0, 0.506, 2.02], ['Team2_Player5', 676, 334.0, 0.494, 1.98]]]
[[['Team1_Player2', 988, 498.5, 0.505, 2.02], ['Team2_Player1', 988, 489.5, 0.495, 1.98]]]
[[['Team1_Player2', 988, 486.5, 0.492, 1.97], ['Team2_Player2', 988, 501.5, 0.508, 2.03]]]
[[['Team1_Player2', 484, 318.5, 0.658, 2.63], ['Team2_Player3', 484, 165.5, 0.342, 1.37]]]
[[['Team1_Player2', 132, 75, 0.568, 2.27], ['Team2_Player4', 132, 57, 0.432, 1.73]]]
[[['Team1_Player2', 704, 389.5, 0.553, 2.21], ['Team2_Player5', 704, 314.5, 0.447, 1.79]]]
[[['Team1_Player3', 616, 291.0, 0.472, 1.89], ['Team2_Player1', 616, 325.0, 0.528, 2.11]]]
[[['Team1_Player3', 836, 381.0, 0.456, 1.82], ['Team2_Player2', 836, 455.0, 0.544, 2.18]]]
[[['Team1_Player3', 836, 375.0, 0.449, 1.8], ['Team2_Player3', 836, 461.0, 0.551, 2.2]]]
[[['Team1_Player3', 572, 255.0, 0.446, 1.78], ['Team2_Player4', 572, 317.0, 0.554, 2.22]]]
[[['Team1_Player3', 572, 318.0, 0.556, 2.22], ['Team2_Player5', 572, 254.0, 0.444, 1.78]]]
[[['Team1_Player4', 156, 79.5, 0.51, 2.04], ['Team2_Player1', 156, 76.5, 0.49, 1.96]]]
[[['Team1_Player4', 832, 391.5, 0.471, 1.88], ['Team2_Player2', 832, 440.5, 0.529, 2.12]]]
[[['Team1_Player4', 728, 320.5, 0.44, 1.76], ['Team2_Player3', 728, 407.5, 0.56, 2.24]]]
[[['Team1_Player4', 676, 291.0, 0.43, 1.72], ['Team2_Player4', 676, 385.0, 0.57, 2.28]]]
[[['Team1_Player4', 988, 424.0, 0.429, 1.72], ['Team2_Player5', 988, 564.0, 0.571, 2.28]]]
[[['Team1_Player5', 988, 416.0, 0.421, 1.68], ['Team2_Player1', 988, 572.0, 0.579, 2.32]]]
[[['Team1_Player5', 308, 173.0, 0.562, 2.25], ['Team2_Player2', 308, 135.0, 0.438, 1.75]]]
[[['Team1_Player5', 392, 193.0, 0.492, 1.97], ['Team2_Player3', 392, 199.0, 0.508, 2.03]]]
[[['Team1_Player5', 448, 217.5, 0.485, 1.94], ['Team2_Player4', 448, 230.5, 0.515, 2.06]]]
[[['Team1_Player5', 84, 40.5, 0.482, 1.93], ['Team2_Player5', 84, 43.5, 0.518, 2.07]]]
```

The list looks like this if I don't print each row:

```
team1_vs_team2_stats = [[[['Team1_Player1', 572, 394.0, 0.689, 2.76], ['Team2_Player1', 572, 178.0, 0.311, 1.24]]],[[['Team1_Player1', 156, 90.5, 0.58, 2.32], ['Team2_Player2', 156, 65.5, 0.42, 1.68]]],[[['Team1_Player1', 832, 449.5, 0.54, 2.16], ['Team2_Player3', 832, 382.5, 0.46, 1.84]]],[[['Team1_Player1', 728, 372.0, 0.511, 2.04], ['Team2_Player4', 728, 356.0, 0.489, 1.96]]],[[['Team1_Player1', 676, 342.0, 0.506, 2.02], ['Team2_Player5', 676, 334.0, 0.494, 1.98]]],[[['Team1_Player2', 988, 498.5, 0.505, 2.02], ['Team2_Player1', 988, 489.5, 0.495, 1.98]]],[[['Team1_Player2', 988, 486.5, 0.492, 1.97], ['Team2_Player2', 988, 501.5, 0.508, 2.03]]],[[['Team1_Player2', 484, 318.5, 0.658, 2.63], ['Team2_Player3', 484, 165.5, 0.342, 1.37]]],[[['Team1_Player2', 132, 75, 0.568, 2.27], ['Team2_Player4', 132, 57, 0.432, 1.73]]],[[['Team1_Player2', 704, 389.5, 0.553, 2.21], ['Team2_Player5', 704, 314.5, 0.447, 1.79]]],[[['Team1_Player3', 616, 291.0, 0.472, 1.89], ['Team2_Player1', 616, 325.0, 0.528, 2.11]]],[[['Team1_Player3', 836, 381.0, 0.456, 1.82], ['Team2_Player2', 836, 455.0, 0.544, 2.18]]],[[['Team1_Player3', 836, 375.0, 0.449, 1.8], ['Team2_Player3', 836, 461.0, 0.551, 2.2]]],[[['Team1_Player3', 572, 255.0, 0.446, 1.78], ['Team2_Player4', 572, 317.0, 0.554, 2.22]]],[[['Team1_Player3', 572, 318.0, 0.556, 2.22], ['Team2_Player5', 572, 254.0, 0.444, 1.78]]],[[['Team1_Player4', 156, 79.5, 0.51, 2.04], ['Team2_Player1', 156, 76.5, 0.49, 1.96]]],[[['Team1_Player4', 832, 391.5, 0.471, 1.88], ['Team2_Player2', 832, 440.5, 0.529, 2.12]]],[[['Team1_Player4', 728, 320.5, 0.44, 1.76], ['Team2_Player3', 728, 407.5, 0.56, 2.24]]],[[['Team1_Player4', 676, 291.0, 0.43, 1.72], ['Team2_Player4', 676, 385.0, 0.57, 2.28]]],[[['Team1_Player4', 988, 424.0, 0.429, 1.72], ['Team2_Player5', 988, 564.0, 0.571, 2.28]]],[[['Team1_Player5', 988, 416.0, 0.421, 1.68], ['Team2_Player1', 988, 572.0, 0.579, 2.32]]],[[['Team1_Player5', 308, 173.0, 0.562, 2.25], ['Team2_Player2', 308, 135.0, 0.438, 1.75]]],[[['Team1_Player5', 392, 193.0, 0.492, 1.97], ['Team2_Player3', 392, 199.0, 0.508, 2.03]]],[[['Team1_Player5', 448, 217.5, 0.485, 1.94], ['Team2_Player4', 448, 230.5, 0.515, 2.06]]],[[['Team1_Player5', 84, 40.5, 0.482, 1.93], ['Team2_Player5', 84, 43.5, 0.518, 2.07]]]]
```

What I would like to do is find the individual match ups between the two teams that will net Team1 the most total team points based on the ProjectedPoints column. If I do it by hand I would get the following results since each player on Team1 has to have a unique opponent from Team2:

```
[[['Team1_Player1', 572, 394.0, 0.689, 2.76], ['Team2_Player1', 572, 178.0, 0.311, 1.24]]]
[[['Team1_Player2', 484, 318.5, 0.658, 2.63], ['Team2_Player3', 484, 165.5, 0.342, 1.37]]]                                                              
[[['Team1_Player3', 572, 318.0, 0.556, 2.22], ['Team2_Player5', 572, 254.0, 0.444, 1.78]]]
[[['Team1_Player4', 676, 291.0, 0.43, 1.72], ['Team2_Player4', 676, 385.0, 0.57, 2.28]]]
[[['Team1_Player5', 308, 173.0, 0.562, 2.25], ['Team2_Player2', 308, 135.0, 0.438, 1.75]]]
```

I have tried using itertools, numpy, and pandas but so far my results haven't been anywhere close to correct and I mostly end up getting errors. I am new to Python and programming in general so any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: you need to find for each unique `TeamPlayer1` biggest value from column `ProjectedPoints` and collect pairs of two teams into new list?

Comment: Not exactly, I am trying to find the best lineup for Team1 versus the opponent roster based on the `ProjectedPoints`. In any given week there are a total of 4 points that a player could win in a head to head match up. For example, `Team1_Player1` vs  `Team2_Player1` I am projecting that `Team1_Player1` would win 2.76 points vs. `Team2_Player1` 1.24 points. For the remaining match ups, `Team1_Player2` can only play against `Team2_Player2`-`Team2_Player5` since Player1 from each team is already matched against each other and this is a head to head competition...

Comment: ...I am trying to find the which match ups Team1 players vs Team2 players that would score the most total  `ProjectedPoints` points for Team1. Hopefully this makes more sense?

Comment: i don't exactly get it how you chose `Team1_Playerx` for the next round and how you find for him a opponent. Opponent must by unique based on earlier selection?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear but it's not a round by round match up. It is a team game where the scores of the individual match ups contribute to the total team score. Which is why each player on Team1 can only match up against a player on Team2 once. All five team members go head to head at the same time, then the individual match points are added to the total team score.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np, itertools

team1_vs_team2_stats = [[[['Team1_Player1', 572, 394.0, 0.689, 2.76], ['Team2_Player1', 572, 178.0, 0.311, 1.24]]],[[['Team1_Player1', 156, 90.5, 0.58, 2.32], ['Team2_Player2', 156, 65.5, 0.42, 1.68]]],[[['Team1_Player1', 832, 449.5, 0.54, 2.16], ['Team2_Player3', 832, 382.5, 0.46, 1.84]]],[[['Team1_Player1', 728, 372.0, 0.511, 2.04], ['Team2_Player4', 728, 356.0, 0.489, 1.96]]],[[['Team1_Player1', 676, 342.0, 0.506, 2.02], ['Team2_Player5', 676, 334.0, 0.494, 1.98]]],[[['Team1_Player2', 988, 498.5, 0.505, 2.02], ['Team2_Player1', 988, 489.5, 0.495, 1.98]]],[[['Team1_Player2', 988, 486.5, 0.492, 1.97], ['Team2_Player2', 988, 501.5, 0.508, 2.03]]],[[['Team1_Player2', 484, 318.5, 0.658, 2.63], ['Team2_Player3', 484, 165.5, 0.342, 1.37]]],[[['Team1_Player2', 132, 75, 0.568, 2.27], ['Team2_Player4', 132, 57, 0.432, 1.73]]],[[['Team1_Player2', 704, 389.5, 0.553, 2.21], ['Team2_Player5', 704, 314.5, 0.447, 1.79]]],[[['Team1_Player3', 616, 291.0, 0.472, 1.89], ['Team2_Player1', 616, 325.0, 0.528, 2.11]]],[[['Team1_Player3', 836, 381.0, 0.456, 1.82], ['Team2_Player2', 836, 455.0, 0.544, 2.18]]],[[['Team1_Player3', 836, 375.0, 0.449, 1.8], ['Team2_Player3', 836, 461.0, 0.551, 2.2]]],[[['Team1_Player3', 572, 255.0, 0.446, 1.78], ['Team2_Player4', 572, 317.0, 0.554, 2.22]]],[[['Team1_Player3', 572, 318.0, 0.556, 2.22], ['Team2_Player5', 572, 254.0, 0.444, 1.78]]],[[['Team1_Player4', 156, 79.5, 0.51, 2.04], ['Team2_Player1', 156, 76.5, 0.49, 1.96]]],[[['Team1_Player4', 832, 391.5, 0.471, 1.88], ['Team2_Player2', 832, 440.5, 0.529, 2.12]]],[[['Team1_Player4', 728, 320.5, 0.44, 1.76], ['Team2_Player3', 728, 407.5, 0.56, 2.24]]],[[['Team1_Player4', 676, 291.0, 0.43, 1.72], ['Team2_Player4', 676, 385.0, 0.57, 2.28]]],[[['Team1_Player4', 988, 424.0, 0.429, 1.72], ['Team2_Player5', 988, 564.0, 0.571, 2.28]]],[[['Team1_Player5', 988, 416.0, 0.421, 1.68], ['Team2_Player1', 988, 572.0, 0.579, 2.32]]],[[['Team1_Player5', 308, 173.0, 0.562, 2.25], ['Team2_Player2', 308, 135.0, 0.438, 1.75]]],[[['Team1_Player5', 392, 193.0, 0.492, 1.97], ['Team2_Player3', 392, 199.0, 0.508, 2.03]]],[[['Team1_Player5', 448, 217.5, 0.485, 1.94], ['Team2_Player4', 448, 230.5, 0.515, 2.06]]],[[['Team1_Player5', 84, 40.5, 0.482, 1.93], ['Team2_Player5', 84, 43.5, 0.518, 2.07]]]]

# form numpy array with all players in one column
arr = np.array(team1_vs_team2_stats).reshape(-1,5)

# form Dataframe for the same, all players in Team column
df = pd.DataFrame(arr,columns = ["Team","TotalPoints", "PointsWon", "WinPct", "ProjectedPoints"]) 

# Create mask to differentiate b/w team 1 and team 2
mask = np.array([True if "Team1" in x else False for x in df.Team]) 

df1 = df[mask].add_suffix("_1").sort_index().reset_index(drop=True) # team 1 df
df2 = df[~mask].add_suffix("_2").sort_index().reset_index(drop=True) # team 2 df

# join both of them
df = pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1).assign(ProjectedPoints_1 = lambda x:pd.to_numeric(x.ProjectedPoints_1))  

# Get number of different players within a team
n = df.Team_1.nunique()

# Get all possible combinations between indices of players of team 1 and team 2
indx = [(x,y) for x in range(0,n*n,n) for y in range(n)]

# Arrange indx such that each player from both the teams is chosen only once
# indx is of form [((0, 0), (5, 1), (10, 2), (15, 3), (20, 4)), .......], 
# sum of each tuple gives the index position of a combination of players from both the team.
# Example ((0, 0), (5, 1), (10, 2), (15, 3), (20, 4)) gives index locations: 0,6,12,18,24, meaning following combination:
#Team1_Player1-Team2_Player1, Team1_Player2-Team2_Player2, Team1_Player3-Team2_Player3, Team1_Player4-Team2_Player4, Team1_Player5-Team2_Player5

indx = [x for x in itertools.combinations(indx,n) if \
     all(xx in (a[0] for a in x) for xx in range(0,n*n,n)) and all(xx in (a[1] for a in x )for xx in range(n))]


# Sum tuples to get indices  
indx = [[sum(x) for x in y] for y in indx]

# Sum the ProjectedPoints_1 value for individual combination
dfs = [sum(df.iloc[x].loc["ProjectedPoints_1"] for x in y) for y in indx]

# get the indices of individual combination
dfs = [i for i, j in enumerate(dfs) if j == max(dfs)]

# multiple final combinations might emerge, hence get all in a list and convert to numpy
dfs = [df[df.index.isin(indx[x])].to_numpy().reshape(-1,2,5) for x in dfs]

print(dfs)

[array([[['Team1_Player1', '572', '394.0', '0.689', 2.76],
        ['Team2_Player1', '572', '178.0', '0.311', '1.24']],

       [['Team1_Player2', '484', '318.5', '0.658', 2.63],
        ['Team2_Player3', '484', '165.5', '0.342', '1.37']],

       [['Team1_Player3', '572', '318.0', '0.556', 2.22],
        ['Team2_Player5', '572', '254.0', '0.444', '1.78']],

       [['Team1_Player4', '676', '291.0', '0.43', 1.72],
        ['Team2_Player4', '676', '385.0', '0.57', '2.28']],

       [['Team1_Player5', '308', '173.0', '0.562', 2.25],
        ['Team2_Player2', '308', '135.0', '0.438', '1.75']]], dtype=object)]
```

Comment: Wow, just wow! This is exactly it what I was trying to accomplish.  Seriously, I can't thank you enough! I had spent 3 days working on this before I posted and was just banging my head against the wall. The only thing I changed in my script was adding a list `team1_roster = ['Team1_Player1', 'Team1_Player2', 'Team1_Player3', 'Team1_Player4', 'Team1_Player5']` and changing the `mask =...` line to `mask = np.array(np.isin(df.Team, team1_roster))`.  In the full script my team will always be Team1 but we have 10 people on the team so the 5 people that make the lineup changes from week to week.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you just want to find the player from Team 1 with maximum ProjectedPoints, among the team 2 players that the first player faced, try the following:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

team1_vs_team2_stats = [[[['Team1_Player1', 572, 394.0, 0.689, 2.76], ['Team2_Player1', 572, 178.0, 0.311, 1.24]]],[[['Team1_Player1', 156, 90.5, 0.58, 2.32], ['Team2_Player2', 156, 65.5, 0.42, 1.68]]],[[['Team1_Player1', 832, 449.5, 0.54, 2.16], ['Team2_Player3', 832, 382.5, 0.46, 1.84]]],[[['Team1_Player1', 728, 372.0, 0.511, 2.04], ['Team2_Player4', 728, 356.0, 0.489, 1.96]]],[[['Team1_Player1', 676, 342.0, 0.506, 2.02], ['Team2_Player5', 676, 334.0, 0.494, 1.98]]],[[['Team1_Player2', 988, 498.5, 0.505, 2.02], ['Team2_Player1', 988, 489.5, 0.495, 1.98]]],[[['Team1_Player2', 988, 486.5, 0.492, 1.97], ['Team2_Player2', 988, 501.5, 0.508, 2.03]]],[[['Team1_Player2', 484, 318.5, 0.658, 2.63], ['Team2_Player3', 484, 165.5, 0.342, 1.37]]],[[['Team1_Player2', 132, 75, 0.568, 2.27], ['Team2_Player4', 132, 57, 0.432, 1.73]]],[[['Team1_Player2', 704, 389.5, 0.553, 2.21], ['Team2_Player5', 704, 314.5, 0.447, 1.79]]],[[['Team1_Player3', 616, 291.0, 0.472, 1.89], ['Team2_Player1', 616, 325.0, 0.528, 2.11]]],[[['Team1_Player3', 836, 381.0, 0.456, 1.82], ['Team2_Player2', 836, 455.0, 0.544, 2.18]]],[[['Team1_Player3', 836, 375.0, 0.449, 1.8], ['Team2_Player3', 836, 461.0, 0.551, 2.2]]],[[['Team1_Player3', 572, 255.0, 0.446, 1.78], ['Team2_Player4', 572, 317.0, 0.554, 2.22]]],[[['Team1_Player3', 572, 318.0, 0.556, 2.22], ['Team2_Player5', 572, 254.0, 0.444, 1.78]]],[[['Team1_Player4', 156, 79.5, 0.51, 2.04], ['Team2_Player1', 156, 76.5, 0.49, 1.96]]],[[['Team1_Player4', 832, 391.5, 0.471, 1.88], ['Team2_Player2', 832, 440.5, 0.529, 2.12]]],[[['Team1_Player4', 728, 320.5, 0.44, 1.76], ['Team2_Player3', 728, 407.5, 0.56, 2.24]]],[[['Team1_Player4', 676, 291.0, 0.43, 1.72], ['Team2_Player4', 676, 385.0, 0.57, 2.28]]],[[['Team1_Player4', 988, 424.0, 0.429, 1.72], ['Team2_Player5', 988, 564.0, 0.571, 2.28]]],[[['Team1_Player5', 988, 416.0, 0.421, 1.68], ['Team2_Player1', 988, 572.0, 0.579, 2.32]]],[[['Team1_Player5', 308, 173.0, 0.562, 2.25], ['Team2_Player2', 308, 135.0, 0.438, 1.75]]],[[['Team1_Player5', 392, 193.0, 0.492, 1.97], ['Team2_Player3', 392, 199.0, 0.508, 2.03]]],[[['Team1_Player5', 448, 217.5, 0.485, 1.94], ['Team2_Player4', 448, 230.5, 0.515, 2.06]]],[[['Team1_Player5', 84, 40.5, 0.482, 1.93], ['Team2_Player5', 84, 43.5, 0.518, 2.07]]]]

# form numpy array with all players in one column
arr = np.array(team1_vs_team2_stats).reshape(-1,5)

# form Dataframe for the same, all players in Team column
df = pd.DataFrame(arr,columns = ["Team","TotalPoints", "PointsWon", "WinPct", "ProjectedPoints"]) 

# Create mask to differentiate b/w team 1 and team 2
mask = np.array([True if "Team1" in x else False for x in df.Team]) 

df1 = df[mask].add_suffix("_1").sort_index().reset_index(drop=True) # team 1 df
df2 = df[~mask].add_suffix("_2").sort_index().reset_index(drop=True) # team 2 df
df = pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1)  # join both of them

# groupby and get maximum ProjectedPoints of team 1
mask1 = df.groupby("Team_1")["ProjectedPoints_1"].transform("max") == df["ProjectedPoints_1"]

# Convert back to numpy array and reshape
print(df[mask1].reset_index(drop=True).to_numpy().reshape(-1,2,5)) 

[[['Team1_Player1' '572' '394.0' '0.689' '2.76']
  ['Team2_Player1' '572' '178.0' '0.311' '1.24']]

 [['Team1_Player2' '484' '318.5' '0.658' '2.63']
  ['Team2_Player3' '484' '165.5' '0.342' '1.37']]

 [['Team1_Player3' '572' '318.0' '0.556' '2.22']
  ['Team2_Player5' '572' '254.0' '0.444' '1.78']]

 [['Team1_Player4' '156' '79.5' '0.51' '2.04']
  ['Team2_Player1' '156' '76.5' '0.49' '1.96']]

 [['Team1_Player5' '308' '173.0' '0.562' '2.25']
  ['Team2_Player2' '308' '135.0' '0.438' '1.75']]]
```

Comment: This is awesome, and really close! The only issue here is that both `Team1_Player1`  and `Team1_Player4` are matched up against `Team2_Player1`. Each week players from Team1 are matched up against a single opponent from Team2 in head to head play. The results from head to head play are then counted toward the total team score. I am trying to find which combination of match ups of players from Team1 would score the most points when totaling the `ProjectedPoints`.

Comment: @JohnnyWisco Check the new answer